# Jquery selector base data attribute with single quote or two quotes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html element with multiple data attributes :

```
 <div class="passenger-information clearfix" data-index="0"   data-class="passenger-info-wrapper" data-age-classify="Adult"></div>
```

I will use jquery selectors as below:

```
1)$('[data-age-classify="Adult"]')
2)$("[data-age-classify='َAdult']")
3)$("[data-class='passenger-info-wrapper']")
```

The problem is that the first selector despite the second and third ones doesn't return anything.

Comment: All above should work

Comment: it should work .. please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and
>   a value, separated by an = character. The attribute value can remain
>   unquoted if it doesn’t contain spaces or any of " ' ` = < or >.
>   Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes.
>   The value, along with the = character, can be omitted altogether if
>   the value is the empty string.

All the cases should work in your example. Check this article for more understanding of the topic: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected.
Please check if there are any console errors on your browser or if jquery library not imported properly.

```js
alert($('[data-age-classify="Adult"]'));
alert($("[data-age-classify='َAdult']"));
alert($("[data-class='passenger-info-wrapper']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="passenger-information clearfix" data-index="0"   data-class="passenger-info-wrapper" data-age-classify="Adult"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of them work, but the second one you dont need the `'`

so it looks like: `$("[data-age-classify=Adult]"`

```js
console.log($('[data-age-classify="Adult"]').html())
console.log($("[data-age-classify=Adult]").html())
console.log($("[data-class='passenger-info-wrapper']").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="passenger-information clearfix" data-index="0"   data-class="passenger-info-wrapper" data-age-classify="Adult">s</div>
```